# Cannot insert the value NULL into column with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using EntityFramework where I'm trying to use a calculated column

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] 
        public bool IsComplete
        {
            get
            {
                if (Steps == null) return false;
                var stepCount = Steps.Count;
                var completedCount = Steps.Count(s => s.IsComplete = true);
                return stepCount == completedCount;
            }
            private set { }
        }
```

But whenever I try to save a new object of my model - is gives me

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsComplete'
```

I thought that a computed column was computed and did not have to contain any data when saving a new object of my model.

anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure you want this as a column in the database? Or do you just want a property in your model?

Comment: Im positive I want it in my database, as my backend needs it - I mean, the backend could calculate it itself and send the data back to the db to be shown in the my view (mvc) but it would be nice if the sql did the actual calculation, so to speak.

Comment: Is there really a computed column on the table that you are mapping to?

Comment: Code First, so there will be

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed means that the database itself should be handling this field and Entity Framework should not be involved in generating this, for example a DEFAULT GETDATE() for a DateCreated field - see computed here 'The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.'

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a5faddeca2be#src/EntityFramework/DataAnnotations/Schema/DatabaseGeneratedOption.cs

It seems to me you are trying to achieve some business logic based on entity data (i.e. CalculateIsComplete()), which possibly should exist outside of your entity. There are a few ways to do this, perhaps you have a service or obvious layer to implement this business logic in your application, or you could use an extension method for example:

```
        public static bool IsComplete(this MyClass obj)
        {
              if (obj.Steps == null) return false;
                var stepCount = obj.Steps.Count;
                var completedCount = obj.Steps.Count(s => s.IsComplete = true);
                return stepCount == completedCount;
        }
```